# Using IIS as a server for non-http server

Tags: web-applications, wcf, server, iis7

I am developing a system that is designed for multiple forms of interfacing. There is a website, but that is connected through an SDK, as well as an HTTP query interface to access data. But to improve speed and quality, I was thinking of creating a system inside IIS that get any message sent to the server, any response, but still let IIS manage SSL and normal socket connections.

Is there a way to host my project in IIS without ASP or any other kind of script with extra behavioral events?

Comment: What are you asking here? It is not clear.

Comment: sorry, im not very clear. how to make iis handle my own protocol without it using any http protocol, but use the ssl and other security elements from iis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By leveraging the [Windows Communications Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) framework, you can create services over a number of different network protocols.  This includes HTTP, HTTPS, MSMQ, and even TCP/IP sockets.  In addition to these, it also support Named Pipes for connections between two processes on the same machine.

IIS can host applications developed for WCF, even if they aren't HTTP or HTTPS based.

For more in-depth information about the different protocols that WCF supports, and information about the relative strengths and weaknesses of each, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx) has good information about this.

While many people have argued that WCF is complicated to configure, it does an excellent job of allowing you to focus on writing code at a fairly high level of abstraction without worrying about the actual transport layer implementation details.  I know of a number of projects that have made excellent use of the MSMQ transport in particular in order to enable durable transports that survive intermittent connectivity.

Comment: Cheers guy, been playing around with it a bit, and its great

Comment: Glad you like it. I think it's cool too.

Comment: I've just asked this if you know a lot about WCF, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529393/wcf-or-php-as-data-distributer

Answer (score 1):

You *could*, but there are likely better solutions.

Two that spring to mind are [TheServerFramework](http://www.serverframework.com/) and the venerable [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) toolkit.

Both of them are general purpose socket/server type frameworks that may serve as more useful jumping off points than IIS would.

If you have control over both sides of the application, as it sounds like you do, then you could also move towards MOM-type solutions like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) or any of the various MOM (Message Oriented Middleware) products on the market, depending on how much control you want or need over the payload and its delivery characteristics.

Good Luck.

Comment: If we're talking about .NET development (which is a probably a reasonable assumption if using IIS) then WCF applications can self-host.